# How to fill the remaining space between two layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've got a problem concerning android layouts.

In my xml file I have two relative layouts. One is attached to the top by android:layout_alignParentTop="true".

The other one is attached to the bottom by android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Now there's a lot of space between these two views. I'd like two fill this remaining space with a FrameLayout where a couple of different fragments should be displayed.

Does anybody know how to fill the space I described?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout" 
   android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"/>
```

Comment: it says, we must specify the `layout_height` and `layout_width` of the `FrameLayout`. Can this be added to a `LinearLayout`

Comment: This answer is incomplete. I also get the height/width requirement.

Answer (score 1):

add your frame layout and set its property

```
< android:layout_above="@+id/top"
     android:layout_below="@+id/bottom" >
```

so the frame layout will occupy thw whole space between these two layouts