# How to fill space between two views within a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have two views. The top view is set to ...

```
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

And the bottom is set to ...

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

How can I fill the remaining space with a third view? According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700886/how-to-fill-the-remaining-space-between-two-layouts), I should use a frame layout like this ...

```
<FrameLayout 
   android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout" 
   android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"/>
```

But then I am required to specify height and width. What height and width am I supposed to specify?

Comment: I think `match_parent` for both will do it.

Comment: I tried that. Must be missing something. Looks like the top and bottom view are just overlapping the middle view.

Comment: Huh. I just tested it, and it works as expected for me.

Comment: I think it's technically more efficient to use `0dp` for the height, but yes either should work.

Comment: The view I am inserting into the frame layout actually looks like this... `<include layout="@layout/view_pager"/>`

Comment: Actually, it seems, with regular Views at least, no matter what height is specified, it still works. Is you're included layout just a ViewPager?

Comment: You're right, it's working. Just had to apply some padding and realized there never was any overlap to begin with...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is my solution

```
<RelativeLayout
     ...
   >
        <YourLayout
         android:id="@+id/toplayout"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

        <YourLayout
         android:id="@+id/bottomlayout"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

        <MiddleLayout 
          <!-- in your case it is FrameLayout -->
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
          <!-- or android:layout_height="wrap_content" according to the_profile -->
           android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout" 
           android:layout_above="@+id/bottomlayout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this help

Comment: thank you so much, I have added it to my answer, hope it can help another person

Comment: works perfectly, pay attention for do not do circular reference, for example when setting the layout_below to bottom element e layout_above to the middle.

Comment: Can I achieve that with constraint layout?

Answer (score 2):

You could take an advantage of weighting. `android:layout_weight` property usually fills whatever space is left (or split equally). In your case it would be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="some_fixed_height"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/middle_one_that_fills"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">   

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as your root layout is a **RelativeLayout** and you're using `layout_alignParentTop` for the top view and `layout_alignParentBottom` for the bottom view, like you mentioned, then it should be working with no need for a middle view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively, if your root view is a **LinearLayout**, you could use the lesser-known, but aptly-named [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) view. Space is:

> a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```